# Elasticsearch groupby query

Tags: t-sql, elasticsearch

I have this mapping in one of the elasticsearch indices:
{FirmID, UserID, ShareID}

The data is something like this:

```
FirmID  UserID  ShareID
f1      u1      1
f1      u1      2
f1      u2      3
f1      u2      4
f2      u3      5
f2      u3      6
f2      u3      7
f2      u4      8
f3      u5      9
f3      u5      10
```

I want to get the FirmID, UserID, Last Share ID(max), number of shares for each user in each firm. 
the TSql query is like:

```
select FirmID, 
UserID, 
Max(ShareID) as LastShareID,
Count(ShareID) as NumberOfShares
from tblShares
group by FirmID, UserID

FirmID  UserID  LastShareID NumberOfShares
f1      u1      2           2
f1      u2      4           2
f2      u3      7           3
f2      u4      8           1
f3      u5      10          2
```

but I need to generate the elasticsearch query. could anyone give me the right query in ES to get the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start you need to define mapping for your type. Since you want to execute aggregation on *string* fields, you need to define them as **keywords**.

```
{
   "mappings": {
     "mytype": {
       "properties": {
         "firmId": { 
           "type": "keyword"
          },
          "userId": {
           "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index your data. Multiple field grouping from sql can be achieved as nested aggregation in Elasticsearch. So first level groups by firmId, second level groups by userId and then we need to add some metrics. Document count is given out of the box, so we only need to add **max** aggregation. So whole query should look like this:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "firm_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "firmId"
      },
       "aggs": {
        "user_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "userId"
          },
          "aggs" : {
            "last_share_id" : { "max" : { "field" : "shareId" } }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your results will be nested, so inside f1 bucket, there will be u1 and u2, and so on.

```
{
   "aggregations":{
      "firm_agg":{
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key":"f1",
               "doc_count":4,
               "user_agg":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"u1",
                        "doc_count":1,
                        "last_share_id":{
                           "value":2.0
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "key":"u2",
                        "doc_count":1,
                        "last_share_id":{
                           "value":4.0
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }

   ...
}
```